# Searching between available dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table as the table below.

```
id  accommodation_id    room_type_id    date_from   date_to
3   1                      2            2017-08-29  2017-09-10 
4   1                      9            2017-08-30  2017-09-08
```

As you can see I have dates from 2017-08-29 to 2017-09-10. Now if I make a search between those dates for example I am searching from 2017-08-25 to 2017-09-15 I should not see any records. I would like to list only if my date is in range between the dates on the table.

Using the query below gets me all the records. How to modify the query to get the result I want?

```
SELECT id, accommodation_id, room_type_id, date_from, date_to
FROM [Agents].[dbo].[Vacancies]
where (date_from >= '2017-08-25' and date_to <= '2017-09-15')
```

I hope I am clear with my question!

Comment: I guess you just need to change the inequality `(date_from <= '2017-08-25' and date_to >= '2017-09-15')`

Comment: What is the datatype of your date columns? `date` and `datetime` behave differently if you have a time component.

Comment: Maybe you should also tell us what result you actually want.

Comment: You have 3 and 5, and if you search from 1 to 7 you should not see any records? Right? Where is logic?

Comment: I am using smalldatetime... I want to get the result only if the date is between the date on the table. example: I have this date on the table 2017-08-29  2017-09-10. If I search 2017-08-31  2017-09-05 I want to see

Comment: It looks to me that you wanna see like 'free rooms in your given period', like those rooms are occupied and your search shouldn't give it back ... I think `yourDateColumn NOT BETWEEN date1 and date2` could do the trick

Comment: If You search between those date ranges you will  obviously see all the results i don't see any logic here

Comment: @Veljko89 Yes I want to see free rooms that I have!

Comment: @Barlet that's great, just adjust question so people can understand it correctly, you'll get answer in no time

Comment: Just be careful if date_to is NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change where clause like this.

```
WHERE 
    ('2017-08-25' between date_from AND date_to ) 
    and ('2017-09-15' between date_from AND date_to )
```